# Python: Trying to import a loop

Tags: python, loops, import

I am new to programming with Python and I have some difficulties with importing a loop I created in order to manipulate some data.

Specifically, in my main script I have the following code:

```
wb=xw.Workbook('/Census/B05.xls')

numbers=range(16,56)

multiples8=range(16,56,8)

data=list(set(numbers)-set(multiples8))

import loop1
```

After I run the command `import loop1`, I get the error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-15-d5d478cf704f>", line 10, in <module>
    import loop1

  File "loop1.py", line 8, in <module>
    for x in set(data):

NameError: name 'data' is not defined.
```

The loop1 script reads:

```
for x in set(data):

        if x-1 in set(multiples8): xw.Range('SQL Results','L'+str(x-1)+':S'+str(x-1)).value=xw.Range('SQL Results','D'+str(x)+':K'+str(x), atleast_2d=True).value

          else:

       if x-2 in set(multiples8): xw.Range('SQL Results','T'+str(x-2)+':AA'+str(x-2)).value=xw.Range('SQL Results','D'+str(x)+':K'+str(x), atleast_2d=True).value

         else:
            if x-3 in set(multiples8):
                    xw.Range('SQL Results','AB'+str(x-3)+':AI'+str(x-3)).value=xw.Range('SQL Results','D'+str(x)+':K'+str(x), atleast_2d=True).value
            else:
                if x-4 in set(multiples8):
                        xw.Range('SQL Results','AJ'+str(x-4)+':AQ'+str(x-4)).value=xw.Range('SQL Results','D'+str(x)+':K'+str(x), atleast_2d=True).value
                else:
                    if x-5 in set(multiples8):
                            xw.Range('SQL Results','AR'+str(x-5)+':AY'+str(x-5)).value=xw.Range('SQL Results','D'+str(x)+':K'+str(x), atleast_2d=True).value
                    else:
                        if x-6 in set(multiples8):
                                xw.Range('SQL Results','AZ'+str(x-6)+':BG'+str(x-6)).value=xw.Range('SQL Results','D'+str(x)+':K'+str(x), atleast_2d=True).value
                        else:
                            if x-7 in set(multiples8):
                                    xw.Range('SQL Results','BH'+str(x-7)+':BO'+str(x-7)).value=xw.Range('SQL Results','D'+str(x)+':K'+str(x), atleast_2d=True).value
```

I would greatly appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: There is an 'edit' link under the question. Can you please fix your indentation? Use the `{}` button in the editor to create a code block.

Comment: Although, your problem is that the `data` variable is not defined in the `loop1.py` file, the importing is not the immediate problem

Comment: How can I make sure that the loop1.py recognizes the data variable, or the other variables for that matter?

Comment: When you import code, it evaluates in it's own namespace, so any previously defined variables are unable to be accessed. You need to use methods and pass around parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to make a method in `loop1.py` that accepts `data` as a parameter, then import that.

```
# loop1.py
def my_loop(data):
    for x in set(data):
        # stuff
```

Then the rest of the code would read

```
wb=xw.Workbook('/Census/B05.xls')

numbers=range(16,56)
multiples8=range(16,56,8)
data=list(set(numbers)-set(multiples8))

from loop1 import my_loop
my_loop(data)
```

Comment: This was just a small example, but you'll also need to import `wx` in loop1.py and pass in the other variables to the method